# Default namespace in Orbeon?

Tags: orbeon, xforms

Regarding wiki about [XML namespace](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xml-namespaces), i don't find any declared default namespace.

So there is no default namespace in Orbeon xforms?

Can i define a default namespace for all elements, and expect to work?
Because i declare it inside xh:html, but then the form doesn't appear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XForms files are XML files. If you wish, you can define the default to the XHTML namespace by adding `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` or XForms by adding `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"` on the root element, but there is no "default namespace by default".

This being said, my recommendation is not to define any default namespace, and always use prefixes. Being explicit, and using the same prefixes across your files, will prevent errors (e.g. ending up with elements in an instance in the XHTML namespace), and make it easier to move code around from one file to the next.